# pip and conda installing identical packages without recognizing duplication

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

So I created a virtual conda env with python 3.5.

I activated it, and pip is installed with python 3.5.

I then installed tensorflow using the virtual env pip as recommended;

I even checked with `pip -V` to make sure that the pip I'm invoking is from the virtual-env site package.

I then installed all the other packages I need like `scikit-learn`, `pandas`, `opencv-python`, etc.  Everything installs and even works fine.

However, I end up with identical packages installed separately by conda and pip, such as with six and numpy.  It also install two different versions of some packages like setuptools.

[image: six]

[image: numpy]

It appears that conda is not recognizing the packages installed by pip.  Anyone else having similar issues?  Anything I'm doing work or should be doing differently?  Thank you.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45390635/2449192 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/51515313/2449192

Comment: Also, please don't post terminal output in images. See here for the reasons: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/40481